# SQL: Count based on two conditions within one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have a table which looks similar to this:

```
+----+----------+--+------------+
| id | entry_id |  |   value    |
+----+----------+--+------------+
|  1 |       20 |  | name       |
|  2 |       20 |  | email      |
|  3 |       20 |  | Menu 1     |
|  4 |       20 |  | 2020-04-23 |
|  5 |       21 |  | name       |
|  6 |       21 |  | email      |
|  7 |       21 |  | Menu 1     |
|  8 |       21 |  | 2020-04-23 |
+----+----------+--+------------+
```

I would now like to count the menus for a certain date which means that I would like to show "2" for menu 1 on 2020-04-23:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     2 |
+-------+
```

My current SQL looks as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(entry_id) FROM my_table WHERE value IN ("Menu 1", "2020-04-23") GROUP BY entry_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

However, this does not seem to work for me. Is there a way to count the entry once if two conditions are fulfilled?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna correct it.

Comment: That's much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You have a very arcane data model.  You have values, but no description of what they are.  I would expect a "key" value somewhere.

You can get all the entries that match using:

```
select entry_id
from my_table
where value in ('2020-04-03', 'Menu 1')
group by entry_id
having count(*) = 2
```

And to get the count:

```
select count(*)
from (select entry_id
      from my_table
      where value in ('2020-04-03', 'Menu 1')
      group by entry_id
      having count(*) = 2
     ) e
```

Comment: there is actually a numeric value for each row, I just left it out. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table with itself to find the rows you want.

For example:

```
select count(distinct id)
from my_table a
join my_table b on a.entry_id = b.entry_id
where b.value = '2020-04-23'
  and a.value = 'Menu 1'
```